# Data from form not getting added into the database table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

I am using Xampp server and want to add the data into the database table. I don't know what am I doing wrong here. The server is up and running. The data from the select box is not getting inserted into the database. I am new to php.

Edit: I have edited my code. I am getting this error:

> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

Test.php

```
<form name="form2" action= "Sub.php" method="post">

<table style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:25px;">Section</th>
          <th style="width:250px;">Definition</th> 
          <th style="width:30px;">Sub Process</th>
          <th style="width:35px;">Response</th>
          <th style="width:30px;">Area</th>
          <th style="width:30px;">Rating</th>
          <th style="width:40px;">Comments</th>
          <th style="width:40px;">Improvement Plan</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="data">
          <td>1.</td>
          <td style="width:500px;">Does Problem Management adheres to incident analysis and trending to identify the problem?</td>
          <td>Problem Detection</td>
          <td>
               <select name="Response[]">


                    <option >--Select Function--</option>
                    <option value="Defined">Defined</option>
                    <option value="Defined and Followed Completely without Automation">
                        Defined and Followed Completely without Automation</option>
                    <option value="Defined and Followed Partially without Automation">
                        Defined and Followed Partially without Automation</option>
                    <option value="Not Defined">
                            Not Defined</option>
                    <option value="Process Present but not followed">
                            Process Present but not followed</option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="Not Applicable">Not Applicable</option>

                </select>
          </td>        
          <td>
            <select name="Area[]">        
                <option >--Select Area--</option>
                <option value="Process">Process</option>
                <option value="Tool">Tool</option>
           </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="Rating[]">        
                <option value="0">--Select Rating--</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
           </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <textarea style="width:80px;" name = "Comments[]" placeholder="Please Provide Comments"></textarea>
          </td>

          <td>
            <textarea style="width:80px;" name = "ImpPlan[]" placeholder="Please suggest Improvements"></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>


    <tr class="data">
          <td>2.</td>
          <td style="width:500px;">Are reactive and proactive problem management understood by teams?</td>
          <td>Problem Detection</td>
          <td>
               <select name="Response[]">        

                    <option>--Select Function--</option>
                    <option value="Defined">Defined</option>
                    <option value="Defined and Followed Completely without Automation">
                        Defined and Followed Completely without Automation</option>
                    <option value="Defined and Followed Partially without Automation">
                        Defined and Followed Partially without Automation</option>
                    <option value="Not Defined">
                            Not Defined</option>
                    <option value="Process Present but not followed">
                            Process Present but not followed</option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="Not Applicable">Not Applicable</option>

                </select>
          </td>        
          <td>
            <select name="Area[]">        
                <option>--Select Area--</option>
                <option value="Process">Process</option>
                <option value="Tool">Tool</option>
           </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="Rating[]">        
                <option value="0">--Select Rating--</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
           </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <textarea style="width:80px;" name = "Comments[]" placeholder="Please Provide Comments"></textarea>
          </td>

          <td>
            <textarea style="width:80px;" name = "ImpPlan[]" placeholder="Please suggest Improvements"></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<br><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">        
</form>
```

Sub.php

```
<?php
$Response1=$_POST['Response'][0];
$Area1=$_POST['Area'][0];
$Rating1=$_POST['Rating'][0];

$Response2=$_POST['Response'][1];
$Area2=$_POST['Area'][1];
$Rating2=$_POST['Rating'][1];

$Comments=$_POST['Comments'];
$ImpPlan=$_POST['ImpPlan'];

$servername= 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'db1';
$port = 3306;

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $port);

echo "Connection successful!" . "<bc>";

$conn->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `problemdet` (Response VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, Area VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, Rating VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Comments VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,    ImprovementPlan VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);');

$sql = "INSERT INTO problemdet (Response, Area, Rating, Comments, ImprovementPlan)
 VALUES ('$Response1', '$Response2', '$Area1', '$Area2', '$Rating1','$Rating2','$Comments', '$ImpPlan')";

if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){

    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "<bc> Error: " .  $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

In the Sub.php you missed quotes ' in this line for $Comments

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO problemdet (Response, Area, Rating, Comments, ImprovementPlan) VALUES ('$Response', '$Area', '$Rating', 
'$Comments', '$ImpPlan')";
```

in Test.php you missed name attribute for select  and placed it in the option tag so change it to

```
<select name="Response[]">        

       <option >--Select Function--</option> ...
```

from

```
<select>        

        <option name="Response">--Select Function--</option> ...
```

in Test.php you there are multiple inputs with same name attribute and in Sub.php you will get just one value so change the names in your name attribute to array

```
<select name="Response[]"> ...
<textarea name = "Comments[]"> ...
```

Then:

```
$_POST['Response'][0] 
$_POST['Response'][1]
$_POST['Comments'][0]
$_POST['Comments'][1]
//and so on if you have to many you can write it in a loop
```

**Edit with explanation**

you should specify the browser that the name attribute(in your case response) is an array(since there are multiple select inputs with same name attribute - response, hence it should be response[])

than in php you should fetch the value from array one by one
(like $_POST['Response'][0],$_POST['Response'][1],.. upto count($_POST['response']))

example in your case

```
<select name="Response[]">
    <option value="first_0">first</option>
    <option value="second_0">second</option>
    <option value="third_0">third</option>
</select>

<select name="Response[]">
    <option value="first_1">first</option>
    <option value="second_2">second</option>
    <option value="third_3">third</option>
</select>
```

if the you select third_0 from 1st select and second_2 from the 2nd that when you fetch the values in php

```
echo $get_select_value_1 = $_POST['Response'][0];
echo $get_select_value_2 = $_POST['Response'][1];

//output will be
third_0 //--$get_select_value_1
second_2 //--$get_select_value_2
```

**Edit 2**  - insert multiple values for same column:

```
$Response1 = $_POST['Response'][0];
$Response2 = $_POST['Response'][1];

$sql = "INSERT INTO problemdet (Response) VALUES ('$Response1'),('$Response2')";//upto so on
```

Edit 3 - test code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form2" action= "register.php" method="post">
    <select name="Response[]">
    <option value="first_0">first</option>
    <option value="second_0">second</option>
    <option value="third_0">third</option>
</select>

<select name="Response[]">
    <option value="first_1">first</option>
    <option value="second_2">second</option>
    <option value="third_3">third</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

sub.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo $Response1 = $_POST['Response'][0];
echo $Response2 = $_POST['Response'][1];
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you @PavanKumar I will surely give your code a try.

Comment: Thanks so much @PavanKumar your corrections worked like a charm. Could you please just elaborate the Array thing with a code which i will be using for the select attribute.Thanks in advance!

Comment: hai I've explained with my words hope you understood.. you can comment if you have any more doubts so that i can search from some links for the refrence

Comment: Well i just wanted to know how would i post this array values in different rows in the mysql database using php

Comment: I've edited my answer is that what you asked for or you are asking for dynamic loop?

Comment: I have edited my code as per your suggested edits and am facing this error.....Notice: Array to string conversion in F:\Xampp\htdocs\Project\Sub.php on line 21. Also the data that is getting inserted into the table is just Array and not the values of the select box.

Comment: check my test code and make sure everything is exactly the same and try again, because I'm not getting any errors